# django2.1.1で画像投稿がうまくできない。

Tags: django

django勉強中のものです。
今、画像投稿の機能をつけようとして、adminページからは登録できるようになったのですが、普通のフォームから投稿しようとすると、できない状態です。
具体的には、下記のようなフォームで画像選択はできるのですが、送信を押してしまうと、画像が選択されていませんと出てしまいます。

[image: 入力段階では選択されていますが]
[image: 送信を押すと保存されていません。実際ディレクトリにも保存されていません。]

環境
dockerで構築
python3.7.3
django2.1.1
pillow:pipでインストール済み

コードは以下のとおりです。

settings.py

```py
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '$tq17%7y8+#&n9m^zn_dfiewt5t@hx=qk3sa3fvzs7kh%#^paq'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'e_journal',
    'stdimage',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'journal.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'journal.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'postgres',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'HOST': 'db',
    'PORT': 5432,
  }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

urls.py

```py
"""journal URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('e_journal.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

forms.py

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import E_journal

class journal_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = E_journal
        fields = ['title','text','photo']
```

models.py

```py
from django.db import models

class E_journal(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=150)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/')
    created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import E_journal
from .forms import journal_form
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST  

def index(request):
    content = E_journal.objects.order_by('-created_datetime')
    return render(request, 'e_journal/index.html',{'content':content})


def detail(request,content_id):
    content = E_journal.objects.get(id = content_id)
    return render(request,'e_journal/detail.html',{'content':content})


def new_journal(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = journal_form(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('E_journal:index')
    else:
        form = journal_form()
    return render(request,'e_journal/new_journal.html',{'form':form})


def edit_journal(request,content_id):
    content=E_journal.objects.get(id = content_id)
    form = journal_form(instance=content)
    return render(request,'e_journal/edit_journal.html',{'form':form,'content':content})

@require_POST
def delete_journal(request,content_id):
    content = E_journal.objects.get(id = content_id)
    content.delete()
    return redirect('E_journal:index')
```

入力フォームのhtml

```html
<div>
  <a href="{% url 'E_journal:index' %}">ホームに戻る</a>
</div>

<form action="{% url 'E_journal:new_journal' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit" class="btn">保存</button>
</form>
```

以上が主なコードです。
回答お願いします。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
formタグの１つ目の要素にenctype="multipart/form-data"をつけたら行けました。
ちなみに、2つ目以降につけるとだめだったので、Ⅰつめじゃないと行けないようです。